# Testing API calls in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, restangular

I am trying to unit test a piece of code that logs in the user to my service using karma/jasmine:

```
  it('should login the user', function () {
      var res;
      runs(function () {
          api.login(1, 'Alex Ventura').then(function (response) {
              res = response;
          });
      });

      waits(2000);

      runs(function () {
          expect(res).toBe({url: "Login", error: 0});
      });

  });
```

But for some reason it seems that the code inside the `then` callback is never being executed (no matter how big the `wait` is). What is the proper way of doing this?

EDIT: The fundamental API is just a wrapper that returns a Restangular promise.

Comment: If you put a failure method on there, what is the failure message?

Comment: It actually does not even hit the error method which I don't understand.